# Uploadify with ruby on rails 'bad content body' 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, upload, uploadify

I'm Getting this error in my development log while uploadify is uploading the file and in the view i get an 'IO ERROR' beside filename.

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Mar 18 11:54:53 -0500 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  bad content body
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:351:in `parse_multipart'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:323:in `loop'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:323:in `parse_multipart'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/request.rb:133:in `POST'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:29:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:58:in `serve'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:103:in `process_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:153:in `with_signal_handler'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:101:in `process_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:78:in `process_each_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:77:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:77:in `process_each_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:76:in `catch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:76:in `process_each_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:51:in `process!'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:23:in `process!'
    dispatch.fcgi:24
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one and worked out perfect for me.

```
BOUNDARY = "AaB03x"

def encode_multipartformdata(parameters = {})
  ret = String.new
  parameters.each do |key, value|
    unless value.empty?
      ret << "\r\n--" << BOUNDARY << "\r\n"
      ret << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"#{key}\"\r\n\r\n"
      ret << value
    end
  end
  ret << "\r\n--" << BOUNDARY << "--\r\n"
end
```

published [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/47e004681a47a5cb?pli=1) ! Good Luck if you're having this problem I hope this one works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try and adjust apache security settings for the app, put this in your vhost config:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Sometimes this processes the parts of files in the `/tmp` and prevents the upload from being finished.